# Remove tooltip when typing command

Tags: texstudio, editors, tooltips

How to remove tooltips that pop up when typing math mode commands? Screenshot below.

The tooltip appears when typing a command, not on mouseover.

I already unchecked the boxes in Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Adv. Editor for "Show image tooltip on image files", "Show help as tooltip on text in editor" and in Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Completion for "ToolTip-Help", "ToolTip-Preview". I also tried unchecking all Permanently active completion files. In Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Preview, I unchecked "Show preview as tooltip on formulas in editor". Nothing changed as a result: same annoying popup covers text.

The problem only occurred today - I have been using TeXstudio for years. I updated audio drivers and did a few restarts today, but did not notice any update being applied to TeXstudio, but maybe that happened in the background.

[image: Tooltip that pops up when typing a command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options->Configure Texstudio-> Completion

Uncheck "Automatically start completer when typing LaTex commands"

[image]